# How should I respond a survey?

Tags: missing-data, survey

As researchers working with survey data know, surveys are plagued with **incomplete or missing data, measurement errors, selection issues**, etc.

I am soon going to take part in a survey. **How should I respond it in order to maximise the information future researchers can get from it?**

My options at the moment are two, but you might be aware of more:

- I do my best to answer everything as accurately as possible. My concern is that by doing this I am increasing selection, since quantity and quality of data would not be random. Would this selection be based on unobservables, hence **missing not at random**, and therefore not ignorable, as per [Rubin (1976)](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/63/3/581.short?rss=1&ssource=mfc)?
- I select a random mechanism through which provide missing info and imprecise answers, in order to *camouflage* myself amid the common respondent, and just be part of the noise. Would this be then **missing completely at random**, and therefore better for researchers?

  PS: yes, I am probably statistically insignificant (unless I deliberately provide with outliers, or sample is small). But still, I am interested on optimal response strategy.

Comment: I am a bit confused. By "national survey" do you mean census? If you don't mean census, I believe that samples in surveys are predetermined (according to sample design variables which determine inclusion probabilities for each unit of the finite population) and therefore I don't see the point of not answering.

Comment: @Easymode44 I mean survey, not census. But when it comes to measurement errors and missing data, it probably makes no difference. Not answering is one option, but what about targeted not answering (i.e. missing data), or measurement errors (e.g. rounding or censoring or blunt lying).